# How to use URLConnection to refresh cache every hour?

Tags: java, caching, urlconnection

I've got a proxy microservice that reads from an API and returns some filtered output. I'm using [HttpsURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) (which uses methods in [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)).

```
String httpsURL = "https://myrestserver/path"+ id ;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxy", 8080));
URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection(proxy);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
con.setDoInput(true);
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() );
result = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

I'd like to use the caches to reduce my traffic and latency, but I'd like to update them every hour.

My question is: **How to use `URLConnection` to refresh cache every hour?**

Assumption - Java 7.

Comment: As in read from the documentation , if you open a Connection again and perform a getInputStream() again , it will cause the data to be refreshed. That in association with a java.util.Timer is possibly what you need. Do i miss something obvious ?

Comment: Don't I need to combine the timer execution with when the micro service is called by a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand , you need to call a repeating client at a fixed interval. Here is a way to do it (Java7). Not sure if this is inline with your need. Here a service call is done every 2 seconds on a dummy URL. Since the task called again and again , the data will be refreshed (Input stream of data will be based on data returned from server)

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CallAPIProxy {
    Timer timer;

    public CallAPIProxy(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        // timer.schedule(new APICallerTask(), seconds * 1000);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new APICallerTask(), 2000, 2000);

    }

    class APICallerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            String httpsURL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
            // String httpsURL = "https://myrestserver/path" + id;
            // Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new
            // InetSocketAddress("myproxy", 8080));
            URL myurl;
            try {
                myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
                System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");

                // HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)
                // myurl.openConnection(proxy);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                // con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                // con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                // String result = new
                // Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                // Scanner result = new Scanner(input);
                StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
                String tmp;
                while ((tmp = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    inputLine.append(tmp);
                    System.out.println(tmp);
                }
                input.close();
                System.out.println("Result " + inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("About to call the API task.");
        new CallAPIProxy(2);
        System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
    }
```